# What does a uniform n-bit string mean?

Tags: encryption

I am a total newbie to cryptography and I would like to know the meaning of a "uniform n-bit string". Also, why keys of that type are commonly used in private-key encryption?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to cryptography. Did you take a basic probability theory? Seems not!  Not a good starting way to cryptography. See [Part I: The Fundamentals](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/part-i-the-fundamentals/). The second part is not clear and the request of a listing is off-topic since too broad. If you ask why uniform since min-Entropy.

Comment: Take a fair coin, throw it once, T=1, H=0, this is the first bit. Now throw it again, this is the second, and so on. This is uniformly and independently generated n-bit string.

Comment: See: [Relation between entropy and min-entropy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63797/18298) and [Why is Min-entropy significant in cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66097/18298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between uniformly and at random in crypto definitions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/what-is-the-difference-between-uniformly-and-at-random-in-crypto-definitions) and also see [Difference between Non-uniformly random and Uniformly random](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/95716/18298)

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you

Comment: +1 for the fast acceptance of the duplicate as my general rule...